# Django-celery task and django transaction

Tags: django, celery, postgresql-9.1, django-celery

I have a question regarding transactions and celery tasks. So it's no mystery to me that of course if you have a transaction and a celery task accessing the same table/records we'll have a race condition.

However, consider the following piece of code:

```
def f(self):
   # function of module that inherits from models.Model
   self.field_a = datetime.now()

   self.save()
   transaction.commit_unless_managed()

   # depending on the configuration of this module
   # this might return None or a datetime object.
   eta = self.get_task_eta()

   if eta:
       celery_task_do_something.apply_async(args=(self.pk, self.__class__),
                                            eta=eta)
   else:
       celery_task_do_something.delay(self.pk, self.__class__)
```

Here's the celery task:

```
def celery_task_do_something(pk, cls):

    o = cls.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if o.field_a:
        # perform something
        return True
    return False
```

As you can see, before creating the task we call `transaction.commit_unless_managed` and it should commit, since django transaction is not currently managed.

However, when running celery task the field `field_a` is not set.

**My question**:

Since we do commit before creating the task, is it still possible that there's a race condition?

**Additional info**

- We're using Postgres version 9.1
- Every transaction is run with READ COMMITTED isolation level
- On a different db with engine `dowant.lib.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2_debugger` `field_a` is already set and the task works as expected. With engine `dowant.lib.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2_hstore_ready` the described issue appears (not sure if it's related with the engine).
- Celery version is 2.2
- I tried different databases. Still the same behavior, except when the engines change. So that's why I mentioned this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should there be a `self.save()` before `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` ?

Comment: ok, in fact there is. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `self.__class__.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=self.pk)` before `save` and see what happens.

It should block all reads to this row untill commit is done.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but since django 1.9

```
transaction.on_commit(lambda: enqueue_atask()))
```